# mySQL Database on a 'server' (For beginner)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database on a server at work.  IT has given me permission to do so, but I really have no idea what I'm doing (doesn't that just scream confidence...).  To give a bit of background information:

1)  On the 'server', it is basically a shared drive at work.  They have given me 'server space', which is basically a file folder that I can use and give access to select users.

2) Only a few people would use this thing, and I only really need a basic basic database. I've worked with mySQL databases before a bit, but only as (localhost).  This server will simply have one table (wooo!) and will eventually, hopefully, be part of a C# program I'm creating to interact with it..

3) I have MySQL Workbench, if that makes things easier.

Basically what I'm wondering, is how do I set up a database on a server?  Is it significantly different than creating one locally?  Is it just a file I have to drag into this folder I'm given?  I have a feeling I have to install something on the server, but I dont' know how / what...

Any help, tips etc is much appreciated!  Cheers

Comment: Please rephrase all this into a question (which ends with a question mark)

Comment: make your question simple and precise ..

Comment: Sorry about that, made edits above

Comment: Having access to a directory doesn't imply you'd be allowed to install/run software from that directory... MySQL does require you run the server software to actually *DO* the database. Having client software like MySQLWorkbench won't let you actually "do" a database. If you can't run software from that shared directory, then look at SQLlite, which is a purely file-based database which doesn't require a server.

Comment: Gothca...  In order to install software to a server, is that something quite involved?  Would there be much risk to installing it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to install software on your server. The MySQL installation process is pretty simple - but it is environment specific, so the windows flavour is different to the Linux/unix flavour. The MySQL site has lots of info on how to do this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing.html).

Installing it is simple, but as it's open source and runs as a daemon/service, most IT departments get a bit antsy. You also need to make sure the network port on which the service "listens" is accessible to the various clients of your app.

Once installed, you need to make sure the MySQL Server starts whenever the machine is rebooted, and runs without specific user privileges (these are characteristics of daemon/service style software). The MySQL documentation is clear and specific on how to do that - but if you don't understand it, you'll need to find someone in the IT department who does.